# How to make a div appear and disappear on click using querySelector and addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got the divs that have the email and password from bootstrap. I have css for the id dropdownlogin, and I did display: none; this is my first post so I hope I have given enough information.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
    {
        document.querySelector("#dropdownlogin").addEventListener('click', function()
        {
            dropdownlogin.style.display = block;
        })
    });
</script>

<div class="login">
    <a href="#">Login</a>
    <center>
        <form id="dropdownlogin" action="">
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
                <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password">
                <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
            </div>
            <div id="loginbtn">
                <button>Login</button>
                <button>Forgot Password</button></p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach the event on the `Login` and on click of you can show or hide the form. Add a class to the `form` and on click of the link toggle the visibility of the form

```js
const formContainer = document.getElementById('dropdownlogin');

function toggleForm(e) {
  formContainer.classList.toggle('hideForm');
}
```

```css
.hideForm {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="login">
  <a href="#" onClick="toggleForm()">Login</a>

  <form id="dropdownlogin" class="hideForm" action="">

    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
      <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-floating">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password">
      <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
    </div>
    <div id="loginbtn">
      <button>Login</button>
      <button>Forgot Password</button>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: @Anton - note the use of class toggling in this answer, which is the preferred way to show/hide elements. +1

Comment: I put this code in and in the inspect on the html page I got this error. Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleForm is not defined. it points to onclick="toggleForm()".

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
 var mydiv = document.querySelector("#dropdownlogin")
 var mybtn = document.querySelector("#mybtn")

 mybtn.addEventListener("click", function () 
    {
       mydiv.classList.toggle("hidden")
    });
</script>

.hidden{
display:none;
}

<div class="login">
    <a href="#">Login</a>
    <center>
        <form id="dropdownlogin" class="hidden" action="">
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
                <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password">
                <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
            </div>
            <div id="loginbtn">
                <button>Login</button>
                <button>Forgot Password</button></p>
            </div>
        </form>
        <button id="mybtn">Click Me!</button>
    </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Please also include a description of how this code fixes the problem. You might also assign the "mybtn" id to the existing link rather than adding an additional button.

Comment: You can just add a click event to the button or link itself and on that click event, you just need to call the toggle function.